# find value of the sum where $j,m,k \geq 0$ $\sum_{j+m+k=100} \frac{100!}{j!m!k!}(-1)^k$

Tags: sequences-and-series, summation

Find value of the sum where $j,m,k \geq 0$ $\sum_{j+m+k=100} \frac{100!}{j!m!k!}(-1)^k$

I really dont have any idea to where to start can any help me

thank you

Answer (score 3):

Your sum is what you get if you expand
$$
(1+1-1)^{100}
$$
according to the (generalisation of) the binomial theorem. (The trinomial theorem?)

Comment: (+1) very nice, yesterday i was watching a tribute to Newton, where the lecturer mentioned the binomial expansion and its generalization and he talked a little bit about trinomial and  higher expansions.